How i can send date of clicked on image in my website that created by wordPress to google sheet and save that?
I want when someone clicks on an image on my website that was designed using WordPress, it will fetch the date of the click and then send it to Google Sheet.
Is there a plugin that does this or is there another way??
i didn't try that
